# What does this icon mean in Eclipse Project Explorer (a number with an up-arrow)?

Tags: eclipse, git

What does this icon mean in Eclipse Project Explorer (a number with an up-arrow)?

"JavaEE" is the name of a brach in Git. "JackPotEE" - is the name of my local Git repo. Project name is "JackPotAlert", name of respective BitBucket repository is same as Project - "JackPotAlert".

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the number of commits by which your branch leads the master. So here your JackpotEE javaEE branch leads your JackpotEE Master(or Develop) branch by 7 commits.